# I knew it already 20 yrs ago vs I knew it as early as 20 yrs ago

Tags: grammar, time, present-perfect, expression-choice

I know that "already" is mainly used with present perfect. I want to emphasise that something was known 20 years ago.

Are the following the same?

> I knew it already 20 yrs ago
>   I knew it as early as 20 yrs ago.

And is this structure correct?

> This has been known already since 1993

(I guess I cannot say "ago" in pres.perfect).

Comment: I would suggest "as early as" to be used with a date. Also I have known this for 20 years

Comment: Yea, I need to emphasise "already" (e.g. it is surprising but antibiotics were discovered as early as 60 years ago). Could it work with "already"?

Comment: _When they came across penicillin, they discovered it had already been discovered_ works. _Discovering that antibiotics has been known already for 60 years, comes as a surprise_ is not quite right - _for as long as_ sounds better but dont' take my word for it. I am not a native speaker

Comment: As early as can also be used for a case, where you miss data in-between. Like (historically probably wrong): *Hopscotch type children games have been played as early as 200 B.C.* Meaning that there are remains found from 200 B.C which indicate that some children played hopscotch, but then the next find is maybe from 1888 (A.C.) so historicans are not sure if they have always been played also between that time points. *Hopscotch type children games have already been played 2000 years ago.* would mean that there have always been kids playing them during that time.

Comment: Then I would use since if I wanted to show continuity...

Comment: But this is not about continous action. You can say "Columbus discovered America in 1492". But if you want to emphasize how early it was (e.g. compared to their possibilites) - "Columbus discovered America as early as in 1492".

Answer (score 2):

[*Already*](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/just-yet-still-already) is not exclusively used with the present perfect (e.g. I [already](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adverbials/adverbials-time/already-still-yet-and-no-longer) ate breakfast this morning). If the action is complete, you can use it with the simple past tense; however, it doesn't fit in your example.

It's hard to say without context, but I don't think I would use the simple past with either of the first two examples. They actually sound more like past perfect to me, but again, it's hard to say without knowing what follows (or precedes) them.

At any rate, the difference between the two is that *already knew* suggests that you've known that information for some unspecified amount of time (e.g., *I/I'd/I've already learned that in school*). Because the time is usually unspecified, *already* is, as you've said, more commonly associated with the present perfect.

When you say *as early as 20 years ago,* you're saying that you've known that for a minimum of 20 years. It's another way of saying *at least.* (e.g., *I/I'd learned that in school as early as 20 years ago*).

As for the next example, the syntax is a little odd. I would probably phrase that like this:

> This has already been known since 1993.

Already is more commonly used before the verb. In cases in which there is one or more auxiliary such as this one, it's normally placed after the first auxiliary.

And while I'm sure that someone can give you an example of an instance in which it's acceptable to use *ago* with the present perfect, it's almost always used with either the simple past or the past perfect to express an action that has been completed at a specific point in time.

In your next example, you can use already. In this case, you'd use the past perfect:

> It is surprising, but antibiotics <del>were</del> *had already been* discovered as early as 60 years ago.

Finally, in your example with Columbus, you would not say *Columbus discovered America as early as in 1492* for two reasons:

First, the year in which Columbus arrived in the Americas is known. It's considered a fact (or I should say it's not commonly disputed). Therefore, you'd say, *Columbus discovered America in 1492.*

And second, *as early as in 1492* is not correct. If you're going to phrase it that way, then it must be, *Columbus discovered America as early as 1492.* You're saying that the exact year is not known when you say *as early as,* so you wouldn't need the preposition *in.* *In 1492* indicates that the event definitely took place in that year.